# Getting the value of checked checkbox in vfp

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

The title says it all, i want to get the value of a checked checkbox whether it is numeric or character so i can save it to a table.

Comment: A checkbox value is either numeric or logical.

Answer (score 1):

You can set yourself what kind of value you want to store in the **check** value property, from the property windows,  if you want to store numerical value then do this, see image: [put the value in 0 or 1](https://prnt.sc/l1tk68)
then you can get the value like this:

```
local nCheckVal as int
nCheckVal=thisform.check.value
```

If you want to store logical values then do this:[Put .t. for true value or .f. for false value](https://prnt.sc/l1tk68)
then you can get the value like this:

```
local lCheckVal as logical
lCheckVal=thisform.check1.value
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know if that is logical or numeric then one easy way would be to cast the value to an integer and check result. If it is either numeric or logical, casted value would be 1\0 for .T..F.:

```
local llChecked
llChecked = ( cast(thisform.myCheckBox.Value as int) = 1 )
```

Although I would disagree, Dhugalmac claims, checkbox value could be a character. I assume it was a typo and meant a logical value's display format may be used as character (like 'Y', 'N', '.T.', '.F.', 'true' ...). Then what I said is still valid with a slight change:

```
local llChecked
llChecked = cast(m.SomeValue as logical)
```

- If it is character and one of logical's castable formats, then it would be true else false.
- If it is numeric, then 0 would be false and any other value true.
- If it is logical already then whatever value it has already.

Comment: Cetin - "Although I would disagree, Dhugalmac claims, checkbox value could be a character."  You mis-read what I said.   I said that if the Check was used as a row SELECTOR in a Grid, the Grid's other field(s) (not the Check) might be any type of field.   So if the user was SCANing through the Grid to find the Checked Rows, then they might want to read the value of its other associated field.

Comment: @Dhugalmac, then I would think you didn't read OP's question nor my answer. OP clearly says "checkbox" and I said "A checkbox ...". In a grid too the sensible type is logical.

Answer (score 0):

Cetin - "A checkbox value is either numeric or logical"
That is true if you are checking for the CHECK itself, but if the user is merely using the check as a Selector for one or more value(s) perhaps in a Grid, then the value being Selected may be different.
Arnold - read the Value into a memory variable and then check the TYPE() of the value.

```
DO CASE
   CASE TYPE('readvalue') = "C"  && Character  
      <do whatever>
   CASE TYPE('readvalue') $ "I,N"  && Integer or Numeric
      <do whatever>
ENDCASE
```

Good Luck

Comment: What do you mean? Would you show me how that is not "true" and checkbox value can be character in code please?